# How to perform assert on any value from array in Selenium IDE?

Tags: javascript, arrays, selenium, automation, selenium-ide

I want to perform assert on text present in some website but there a few valid values for this case and not only one.
I made array with the 3 possible valid results for this case and I don't know how to call them from the assert command.
Please advise.

This is my code (I need solution for line 8):

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>new Array ('0 minutes ago','1 minute ago','1 hour ago')</td>
    <td>validEmail</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>assertTextPresent</td>
    <td>${validEmail[0]} || ${validEmail[1]} || ${validEmail[2]}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: At the moment, it looks a little bit like you have created a separate account, which you are using to make major edits to this question. If you want to change the content of the question, please use the same account!

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things here. Number 1 is you're not telling the command where to look on the page for this text, so your target line in your example should be your value, and your target line should contain the relevant css locator/xpath. Also, if it's checking for a value on the page you would probably be better off using 'verifyTextPresent' so:

```
<td>verifyTextPresent</td>
<td>css=body</td>
<td>*${validEmail[0]} || ${validEmail[1]} || ${validEmail[2]}*</td>
```

I've put the *wildcards in this example as it would be checking the full body of the page, however if you know the specific locator for the exact text you're checking they wouldn't be needed. However I'm not familiar with the way you're trying to verify against 3 potential values in one command, so I'm not sure if that would work, or if it would need splitting out into 3 separate verify commands, however you'd potentially have 2 steps failing.

I know there are plugins to selenium which allow for if/else statements so there me be one which would allow you to check for the 3 values separately.